# Android Studio Firebase Data Not Added To ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have code like this. i want to add data to recyclerView to display

[image]

Data is fetched successfully and successfully in the Log, but the data is not added to the ArrayList.
when i do it manually without fetching data from firebase, the data is displayed normally.

How do I add data to an ArrayList correctly so that the data is displayed in the recyclerview?

Comment: You say "the data is not added to the ArrayList". How are you checking that?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code as text as well?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)